# Using Thymeleaf to iterate cards then send value of selected card to model

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf to spit out cards for all of the objects in a list but I want the user to be able to click a button on one of these cards and then let my backend know which card (`baseElement.name`) has been selected by sending back the name of the `baseElement`. This is working great with a dropdown menu instead of cards but I would much rather use cards for user experience.

In debug mode I see that `selectedElementName` comes back as empty string, so where I'm trying to fill it with `baseElement.name` doesn't seem to be working.

View:

```html
<th:block th:each="baseElement : ${baseElements}">
   <div class="col-md">
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post"
         th:action="@{/account/baseElementLevel}" th:object="${selectedElementName}">
         <div class="card text-center g-4">
            <div class="card-header">Base Element</div>
            <div >
               <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title" name="selectedElementName" id="selectedElementName" th:value="${baseElement.name}" th:text="${baseElement.name}"></h5>
                  <p class="card-text" th:text="${baseElement.briefDescription}"></p>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit">Enter</button>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">Entry Points:</div>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</th:block>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/baseElementLevel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String baseElementLevel(Model model, Principal principal) {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
    List<BaseElement> baseElements = elementService.findByUserUserIdAndType(user.getUserId(), "BASE");
    
    model.addAttribute("baseElements", baseElements);

    model.addAttribute("selectedElementName", "");
    model.addAttribute("baseElement", "");

    model.addAttribute("amount", "");

    return "baseElementLevel";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/baseElementLevel", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String baseElementLevelPOST(@ModelAttribute("amount") String amount,
        @ModelAttribute("selectedElementName") String selectedElementName, Principal principal) {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());

    user.setSelectedBaseElement(
            elementService.findByNameAndUserUserId(selectedElementName, user.getUserId()).getId());


    userService.save(user);

    return "redirect:/account/elementView";
}
```

I'm trying to display a list of elements so that each gets a card which displays the element's information and then a button on each card to post and tell the controller which card the user selected.

I can get it to work just fine if I replace cards with a select drop down but not sure how to get this lined up with cards for each list item.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h5 />`s don't get submitted when you submit a form.  you could use a hidden form element for this:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${baseElement.name}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="selectedElementName" th:value="${baseElement.name}" />
  <p class="card-text" th:text="${baseElement.briefDescription}" />
  <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit">Enter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thank yo so much, that worked perfectly. I'm new to thymeleaf and front end development in general so I'm very grateful. That's helpful to know. I will have to look more into form submission and get an understanding of what does and does not get submitted. Thank you so much.